# Adsense Pre-loading policy

Tags: ads, adsense, policy

i used Buzzy Script for my web site and buzzy script support Pre-loading page 
when a user goto to down of post it load new post in that page user can view 100 of post in one page and also load 100 adsense ads on one page 
http://buzzy.akbilisim.com/news/cute-or-creepy-avatar-babies-are-freaking-the-internet-out
what is Adsense Pre-loading policy for that this ?????/
adsense not block my account for that???

Answer (score 0):

Responsive AdSense Ads (Another Approach)

Whether you set data-ad-format as “auto” or “vertical” or “horizontal” or vertical, the Google AdSense algorithms will still decide which ad to serve. For instance, if you ask for an rectangle, you may either get a medium rectangle or a large rectangle.

SHould you wish to force AdSense to serve ads of a particular size while staying responsive, you can consider custom-sized ads. The size of these ads is determined based on the screen but the publisher has more control over the banner size that is served.

```
<div id="google-ads-1"></div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

    /* Calculate the width of available ad space */
    ad = document.getElementById('google-ads-1');

    if (ad.getBoundingClientRect().width) {
        adWidth = ad.getBoundingClientRect().width; // for modern browsers 
    } else {
        adWidth = ad.offsetWidth; // for old IE 
    }

    /* Replace ca-pub-XXX with your AdSense Publisher ID */ 
    google_ad_client = "ca-pub-XXX";

    /* Replace 1234567890 with the AdSense Ad Slot ID */ 
    google_ad_slot = "1234567890";

    /* Do not change anything after this line */
    if ( adWidth >= 728 )
      google_ad_size = ["728", "90"];  /* Leaderboard 728x90 */
    else if ( adWidth >= 468 )
      google_ad_size = ["468", "60"];  /* Banner (468 x 60) */
    else if ( adWidth >= 336 )
      google_ad_size = ["336", "280"]; /* Large Rectangle (336 x 280) */
    else if ( adWidth >= 300 )
      google_ad_size = ["300", "250"]; /* Medium Rectangle (300 x 250) */
    else if ( adWidth >= 250 )
      google_ad_size = ["250", "250"]; /* Square (250 x 250) */
    else if ( adWidth >= 200 )
      google_ad_size = ["200", "200"]; /* Small Square (200 x 200) */
    else if ( adWidth >= 180 )
      google_ad_size = ["180", "150"]; /* Small Rectangle (180 x 150) */
    else
      google_ad_size = ["125", "125"]; /* Button (125 x 125) */

    document.write (
     '<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:' 
      + google_ad_size[0] + 'px;height:' 
      + google_ad_size[1] + 'px" data-ad-client="' 
      + google_ad_client + '" data-ad-slot="' 
      + google_ad_slot + '"></ins>'
    );

    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});

</script>

<script async src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js">
</script>
```

Go to your AdSense dashboard and either create a new ad unit or use one of your existing ad units. Make a note of the ID of your ad unit and also your AdSense Publisher ID and paste these values in Line #15 and #18.

Next, copy-paste the above snippet anywhere on your web page and, based on the size of the user’s device, the most appropriate AdSense Ad will be served. If you wish to include multiple responsive AdSense ad units on the same web page, just use the same snippet of code but increment the DIV ID in lines #1 & #6 such that they become google-ads-1, google-ads-2 and so on.
I hope this will help you.

Comment: i want to know that  if i show 100 adsense per page
adsense not block my account??? 
http://rana.press/news/obama-trump-hold-excellent-white-house-talks

Comment: I see. don't worry about that. don't have any policy prevent you put more adsense per page. Just don't click your self.